# Unable to drop LVM2 snapshot of rootfs

Tags: lvm

Before upgrading my server from Debian Jessie to Debian Stretch, I created a LVM2 snapshot of my rootfs (`/`).

Here is how my storage currently looks like according to several tools. `/dev/intraid/root` is my original rootfs, and `/dev/intraid/root-snapshot` is the snapshot:

```
$ sudo lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/intraid/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                intraid
  LV UUID                0d5hwZ-07Lv-3Yxb-cff3-95za-Rrcx-9y6eQv
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time newsrv, 2015-05-26 09:32:04 +0800
  LV snapshot status     source of
                         root-snapshot [active]
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                3.18 TiB
  Current LE             834465
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/intraid/root-snapshot
  LV Name                root-snapshot
  VG Name                intraid
  LV UUID                A9sjTI-gcV8-WTLi-wZ0I-J7O6-4hdc-AQSxZj
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time newsrv, 2018-05-04 19:25:12 +0800
  LV snapshot status     active destination for root
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                3.18 TiB
  Current LE             834465
  COW-table size         180.00 GiB
  COW-table LE           46080
  Allocated to snapshot  57.08%
  Snapshot chunk size    4.00 KiB
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:3


$ lsblk -t
sdf                                      0   4096       0    4096     512    1 cfq       128  128    0B
├─sdf1                                   0   4096       0    4096     512    1 cfq       128  128    0B
├─sdf2                                   0   4096       0    4096     512    1 cfq       128  128    0B
│ └─md0                                  0   4096       0    4096     512    1           128  128    0B
│   ├─intraid-root-real                  0   4096       0    4096     512    1           128  128    0B
│   │ ├─intraid-root                     0   4096       0    4096     512    1           128  128    0B
│   │ └─intraid-root--snapshot           0   4096       0    4096     512    1           128  128    0B
│   └─intraid-root--snapshot-cow         0   4096       0    4096     512    1           128  128    0B
│     └─intraid-root--snapshot           0   4096       0    4096     512    1           128  128    0B
└─sdf3                                   0   4096       0    4096     512    1 cfq       128  128    0B
sdg                                      0   4096       0    4096     512    1 cfq       128  128    0B
├─sdg1                                   0   4096       0    4096     512    1 cfq       128  128    0B
├─sdg2                                   0   4096       0    4096     512    1 cfq       128  128    0B
│ └─md0                                  0   4096       0    4096     512    1           128  128    0B
│   ├─intraid-root-real                  0   4096       0    4096     512    1           128  128    0B
│   │ ├─intraid-root                     0   4096       0    4096     512    1           128  128    0B
│   │ └─intraid-root--snapshot           0   4096       0    4096     512    1           128  128    0B
│   └─intraid-root--snapshot-cow         0   4096       0    4096     512    1           128  128    0B
│     └─intraid-root--snapshot           0   4096       0    4096     512    1           128  128    0B
└─sdg3                                   0   4096       0    4096     512    1 cfq       128  128    0B

$ sudo blkid
/dev/sdf1: UUID="C622-1FAD" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="3d63a1ce-dd19-4396-9f9c-7894a4e9b256"
/dev/sdf2: UUID="3eb2349d-df83-c9a5-7151-9bdcb40449f8" UUID_SUB="b04a81da-8279-8ade-130d-65478f415085" LABEL="newsrv:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="607b2070-1de3-4e58-89f4-401d3144d52c"
/dev/sdf3: UUID="9b8fb3d2-4bb3-4a48-8b26-23af503b9d28" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="8778cdc1-1fd8-4af0-b7a0-9dbca0d137fa"
/dev/sdg1: UUID="C623-571D" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="56f5dc2f-0562-4590-a54d-8c705dfef79f"
/dev/sdg2: UUID="3eb2349d-df83-c9a5-7151-9bdcb40449f8" UUID_SUB="8370e4ce-6b8b-5cdf-1043-60e748758898" LABEL="newsrv:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="ee82035a-6e8a-4bb8-9828-336ee85d3afd"
/dev/sdg3: UUID="a3062d00-d91b-490d-b366-7cfbfb42c09d" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="fb6b3047-bfd4-4502-97ba-1a58197e75f4"
/dev/md0: UUID="44gLpv-engQ-I0KW-VJ0e-2Q6Z-OCeI-m0HSWq" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/intraid-root: UUID="a96458d1-87d6-4cf6-a004-7b8ceb3ae31f" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/mapper/intraid-root--snapshot: UUID="a96458d1-87d6-4cf6-a004-7b8ceb3ae31f" TYPE="xfs"

$ mount
/dev/mapper/intraid-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/mapper/intraid-root on /srv/matlab_chroot/usr/local/MATLAB type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/mapper/intraid-root on /srv/matlab_chroot/shared_home type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/sdf1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/intraid-root on /srv/matlab_chroot/mnt/nethome-new type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)

$ sudo lsof /dev/mapper/intraid-root--snapshot
COMMAND      PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE      SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
grub-moun 218357 root    3r   BLK  253,3 0x32ee7fe0000 2115 /dev/mapper/../dm-3

$ sudo lsof /dev/intraid/root-snapshot
COMMAND      PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE      SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
grub-moun 218357 root    3r   BLK  253,3 0x32ee7fe0000 2115 /dev/intraid/../dm-3

$ sudo lsof /dev/mapper/intraid-root--snapshot-cow

$ sudo lsof /dev/mapper/intraid-root-real

$ findmnt
TARGET                                SOURCE                           FSTYPE          OPTIONS
/                                     /dev/mapper/intraid-root         xfs             rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
├─/srv/matlab_chroot/usr/local/MATLAB /dev/mapper/intraid-root[/usr/local/MATLAB]
│                                                                      xfs             rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
├─/srv/matlab_chroot/shared_home      /dev/mapper/intraid-root[/home]  xfs             rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
├─/srv/matlab_chroot/mnt/nethome-new  /dev/mapper/intraid-root[/mnt/nethome-new]
```

Note that the snapshot is not mounted according to the output of `mount`.

However, when I attempt to drop the snapshot, I get this message:

```
$ sudo lvremove -f intraid/root-snapshot
  Logical volume intraid/root-snapshot in use.
```

What am I supposed to do so I can drop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mount` command output has clearly been trimmed. Unfortunately it looks like you cut off something that is relevant to the question.

It looks like process 218357 might be still accessing the snapshot. By the partial command name it seems to be `grub-mount`. Since it uses FUSE and GRUB's drivers for accessing the filesystem, it accesses the LV device directly as a "raw disk device".

For the same reason, it is not visible as a regular mount. I just mounted my `/dev/sda1` with `grub-mount`, and it looks like this:

```
# grub-mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
# mount
[...other mount points omitted...]
grub-mount on /mnt type fuse.grub-mount (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
```

Note that the `grub-mount`ed filesystem shows up as type `fuse.grub-mount` and the line does not indicate which disk device is actually mounted. The second `fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections` mount entry appears always when FUSE-based mount entries are used: it is part of FUSE's interface.

So, first locate and unmount the `grub-mount` as it seems to be holding the snapshot device open. After it's been unmounted, you should be able to remove the snapshot normally, with the command you originally tried.

Comment: I had guessed that it had to do with `grub-mount`. But do you know what is `grub-mount` doing there? The man page of `grub-mount` says "export GRUB filesystem with FUSE". I have no idea what that means.

Comment: You can use `grub-mount` to mount in read-only mode any filesystem that GRUB can read, completely separate from regular filesystem drivers. Since it's absolutely read-only, it might be useful in some data recovery operations, or for verifying that GRUB sees a particular disk correctly. Without seeing at least the full command line of your process #218357, I cannot guess what it might be for. (`ps -fp 218357`) You might try finding out who has set up that `grub-mount` and asking him/her?

Comment: I could drop the snapshot once I had rebooted the machine and `grub-mount` was no longer mounting the snapshot. Marking this as answered.